# Android ViewModel relationship to View without Context

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel

I am having a hard time understanding how to migrate to the Google sanctioned Android modern development.  In MVVM the "business logic" should be in the ViewModel, and it is recommended that subclasses of ViewModel should be Context unaware, but most Android classes require a Context in order to provide any functionality.  For example, references to system services cannot be acquired without a Context (like the WifiManager and ConnectivityManager).

As an example, I'm trying to build a simple architecture for an app with a single button which changes its image according to the active default network link as outlined in the ConnectivityManager documentation.  This **system level** operation should be handled in the 'business logic' area of code since it has nothing to do with UI.  It detects a network state, changes some state data in the ViewModel which should *magically* change the button image due to some Observable which notifies the UI that data has changed and triggers a Compose 'Recomposition' which changes the button image.  I have started to build this app and I'll post what I have so far.  How can one create a ViewModel without a Context if the ViewModel is the arbiter of app state?  This seems paradoxical.

ViewModel excerpt:

```
enum class ConnectivityState {
    WIFI,
    CELLULAR,
    DISCONNECTED
}

class MainActivityViewModel(context: Context) : ViewModel() {
    private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)

    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(MainUIState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<MainUIState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    //TODO: how to perform system level business logic in ViewModel without Context reference?
    //DESIRED: keep this 'business logic' away from UI.  ViewModel should be appropriate but Context should not be used here?
    private val wifiManager =
        context.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
    private val connectivityManager =
        context.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

    /**
     * a NetworkCallback which will be triggered when a change in network state is sent from the system
     */
    private val networkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
            super.onAvailable(network)
            _uiState.value.connectivityState = getConnectivityState()
        }

        override fun onCapabilitiesChanged(
            network: Network,
            networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities
        ) {
            super.onCapabilitiesChanged(network, networkCapabilities)
            _uiState.value.connectivityState = getConnectivityState()
        }

        override fun onLost(network: Network) {
            super.onLost(network)
            _uiState.value.connectivityState = getConnectivityState()
        }
    }

    init {
        connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(networkCallback)
        _uiState.value.connectivityState = getConnectivityState()
    }

    fun getConnectivityState(): ConnectivityState {
        //these objects represent information about the currently active network
        val currentNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()
        val capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(currentNetwork)
        val linkProperties = connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(currentNetwork)

        if(currentNetwork == null) {
            return ConnectivityState.DISCONNECTED
        }

        if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled) {
            //if wifi is enabled, it should be the current active network
            val isWifi = capabilities?.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
            if(isWifi != null) {
                if(isWifi) {
                    //the current active link is a WiFi connection
                    logger.debug("Current active default network is WiFi.")
                    return ConnectivityState.WIFI
                }
            }
        }

        val isCellular = capabilities?.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
        if(isCellular != null) {
            if(isCellular) {
                logger.info("Current active default network is cellular data.")
                return ConnectivityState.CELLULAR
            }
        }

        return ConnectivityState.DISCONNECTED
    }
}

data class MainUIState(
    var connectivityState: ConnectivityState = ConnectivityState.DISCONNECTED
)
```

Activity excerpt:

```
    @Composable
    fun wifiComposable() {
        //WiFi button
        Button(
            onClick = {
                MainActivity.openWifiSettings(LocalContext.current)
            }
        ) {
            //TODO: this image changes between DOWN, CELLULAR, WIFI images depending on connectivity state / source
            Image(
                //TODO: 'StateFlow.value should not be called within composition' why?
                //DESIRED BEHAVIOR: when this state value changes, recomp and change image accordingly
                painter = when(viewModel.uiState.value.connectivityState) {
                    ConnectivityState.WIFI -> painterResource(id = R.drawable.wifi_indicator)
                    ConnectivityState.CELLULAR -> painterResource(id = R.drawable.cellular_indicator)
                    ConnectivityState.DISCONNECTED -> painterResource(id = R.drawable.down_indicator)
                },
                modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp),
                contentDescription = "WiFi Settings")
        }
    }
```

Comment: It should be mostly context unaware. The entire trick that is (ab)used is capturing instance of your "Application" context which is an odd pattern but safe as far as "leaking context" goes. You can either do it yourself or extend "AndroidViewModel" which is handled by default viewmodel factory. Just be aware of what you use it for and avoid capturing resources it provides since those are subject to configuration changes.

Comment: If Google really meant it, they wouldn't be providing official samples that directly contradict their advice.  - https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Jetcaster/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetcaster/Graph.kt   Its a singleton that is provided with context in Application - https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Jetcaster/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetcaster/JetcasterApplication.kt and then consumed in videmodel - https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Jetcaster/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetcaster/ui/home/category/PodcastCategoryViewModel.kt

Comment: @Pawel If you write that comment in the form of an answer, I'll accept it, since that's what I ended up doing (right or wrong).  I ended up extending from AndroidViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

In the architectural approaches recommended by Google, at least 2 layers are recommended. (Presentation - Data Layer)

**Presentation - UI Layer**

The UI layer that displays application data on the screen.

> The role of the UI is to display the application data on the screen
> and also to serve as the primary point of user interaction. Whenever
> the data changes, either due to user interaction (like pressing a
> button) or external input (like a network response), the UI should
> update to reflect those changes. Effectively, the UI is a visual
> representation of the application state as retrieved from the data
> layer.

ViewModel is considered as State Holder.

[image: State Holder - Android]

**Data Layer**

The data layer that contains the business logic of your app and exposes application data.

In your case, set the Network status as a datasource. I recommend injecting Context with Dagger Hilt. This is business logic after all. An operation is performed on a data. It is good practice to access it as a Singleton.

[image: Data Layer - Android]

[image: Google Architecture Guide]

Answer (score 1):

That is where separation of concern and ideally dependency injection come into play.

Your view model should be concerned about serving the right data for the specific view. This can be a small component or a whole screen.

The view model itself relies on other classes that supply it with the required data. This can be services that make web API calls, load data from the DB or system services that check the network state.

The services should be passed into the view model as parameters like this:

```
// In this context, NetworkService is some kind of helper class that is
// supposed to take care of network state related code
class MainActivityViewModel(networkService: NetworkService : ViewModel() {
  fun getConnectivityState(): ConnectivityState {
    return networkService.getConnectivityState()
  }
}
```

Now your view model itself doesn't require a context. But still, the `NetworkService` probably needs one.

```
interface NetworkService {
  fun getConnectivityState(): ConnectivityState
}


class NetworkServiceImpl(context: Context) : NetworkService{
  // TODO: Initialize a connectivity manager

  fun getConnectivityState(): ConnectivityState {
    // TODO get the actual ConnectivityState  
  }
}
```

At this point you can make the `NetworkService` a singleton (in Kotlin you can exchange `class` for `object`) and initialize it in an Activity or Application class.

The suggested approach however is to use dependency injection (with Hilt) to abstract all of this away.
See [Dependency injection with Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android)